# How do you survive the skyfall cheat?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

While playing GTA5, I came across a cheat called [skyfall](http://www.xbox360cheats.com/Grand_Theft_Auto_V/Skyfall_Skydiving/) on the XBox360. After playing around with it and having a laugh, I managed to accidentally survive the cheat. When using the skyfall cheat, you will spawn in the air WITHOUT a parachute and you will fall and inevitably die when you hit the ground.

However, is there a way to survive this cheat? I have heard of people doing it but I never found out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to survive this cheat and it is not that difficult either! When you spawn in the air, simply manoeuvre yourself till you are about to collide into the wall and just before you crashland, ram into it. Somehow, this will cause you to only take the impact damage of ramming into the wall and not the full fall damage.

Note: you can ram into anything, a lamp post, car (as shown above) or a building.

Answer (score -2):

it sounds crazy but for me if i go straight down and face plant i usually survive